# Как создать выборку определенного слова в SQL с библиотекой asyncpg в Python?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

Во время написания программы наткнулся на такую ошибку:

Хотел я как-то выбрать из поля `subject` предмет *Физика*, но проблема была в том что там предметы записаны через запятую "Алгебра, Физика, Геометрия".

ну я и написал следующий код:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE subject LIKE $1` - где $1 = '%Физика%', так-же ставил и просто 'Физика'

В общем я не знаю как в `asyncpg` использовать `LIKE` и `%`!

asyncpg на python

Есть таблица `users` у которого имеются столбцы `username` и `subject`, оба имеют тип данных `str`, в столбце `subject` предметы подписаны через запятую как `Алгебра, Физика, Геометрия`

И мне оттуда надо вытащить `username` где в `subject` у него есть `Физика`

Comment: Укажите точно используемую СУБД.

Comment: я использую модуль `asyncpg` для отправки запросов на сервер базы данных и всё, через него я и создал базу данных, таблицы, и заполнял их

Comment: Збс... а сервер БД - какой? нет, я понимаю, что библиотека заточена под PostgreSQL - но гарантий-то никаких. А уж версию сервера БД угадать и вовсе нереально.

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.3

Comment: В таком случае запрос - правильный, и он соответствует той форме, которая указана в документации на библиотеку. Возможно, проблема именно в коде питона, а не на стороне SQL-сервера. Показывайте код, со всей обвязкой.